# Bit hack to return one of two values depending on the value of the second

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Suppose `x` is a bit mask (ie all of its bits except for one are 0) and `y` is either a bit mask or is equal to 0. I need a bit hack to return `x` if `y` is non-zero and return zero if `y` is zero.

Here's one possible solution: take the base-2 logarithm of `x` and `y` (using de Bruijn sequence) and subtract them, storing the value in `d`. Then `y << d` will return `x` unless `y` was zero to begin with.

Two problems with this approach: 1) if `y` is zero, technically the base-2 logarithm is undefined. Not sure if that matters though, because even if `d` is some garbage value, `y << d` should still return zero if `y` is zero; 2) if `d` is negative, the right-shift operator does not become a left-shift operator (according to Google search), meaning that I'll have to include some sign checking.

I'm convinced that there's a simpler approach, but I can't find it and would appreciate some help.

EDIT: to clarify, I'm looking for the fastest way to do this. The obvious `if (y == 0) return 0; else return x` uses an `if` statement and hence suffers from the adverse effects of branch prediction, which is why I'm resorting to convoluted base-2 log solutions.

Comment: Don't know why this calls for all the proposed complexity. `return y ? x : 0;` satisfies the stated requirements.

Comment: I've read this several times now.  I still don't understand the big problem.  Logs?

Comment: Smells like too much studied cleverness to me - expect the original poster to pull out a white rabbit out of a heretofore concealed top-hat any moment now ;)

Comment: @PeteBecker I should have made it more clear that I'm trying to avoid an `if` statement, because branch prediction will slow things down due to an unpredictable branch.

Comment: LOL!   I will be sure to use FP expansions in place of conditional jumps in future:)

Comment: @MartinJames There are no floating points. `x` and `y` are powers of two and hence the base-2 log algorithm I referenced returns an integer.

Comment: @Alessandro Power If the ternary operator isn't palatable for some reason, you could use  `result = (0 - (y != 0)) & x`, assuming your platform stores integers in two's complement format [all I know do].

Comment: @njuffa Clever and clean solution, I'll accept it if you include it as an answer.

Comment: Have you measured it's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of the ternary operator would be preferred on most common processor architectures:

```
/* if y != 0, return x, else return 0 */
int select1 (int x, int y)
{
    return y ? x : 0;
}
```

The use of the ternary operator does not typically involve the use of branches on modern processor architectures, since it can easily be implemented in branchless fashion by using conditional moves (e.g. on x86), instruction predication (e.g. on ARM), or select instructions (e.g. on some GPUs).

If use of the ternary operator is not desired or allowed, and a bit-twiddly solution is required, one could (assuming the platform uses two's complement representation for integers) use:

```
/* if y != 0, return x, else return 0 */
int select2 (int x, int y)
{
    return (0 - (y != 0)) & x;
}
```

Note that `select2()` is likely to be *slower* than `select1()`. Example: If I compile the above functions for the x86-64 architecture my compiler produces this instruction sequence for `select1()`

```
test      edx, edx
cmovne    edx, ecx
mov       eax, edx
ret
```

but this longer instruction sequence for `select2()`:

```
mov       r8d, 1
test      edx, edx
cmovne    edx, r8d
neg       edx
and       edx, ecx
mov       eax, edx
ret
```

Note that neither instruction sequence involves branching as part of value selection, but the instruction sequence in `select2()` requires more instructions to be executed and also has a longer dependency chain, compared to the instruction sequence in `select1()`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. How do you know that the second solution will be slower than the first? It may have more instructions, but does that necessarily make it slower? My understanding was that a failed branch prediction will force the instruction pipeline to clear, which could take several extra clock cycles.

Comment: Neither of the two solutions involves branching as part of the value selection, but `select2()` requires both more instructions *and* has a longer dependency chain.

Comment: Okay, so I take it that the compiler optimized the branching away?

Comment: Use of the ternary operator doesn't typically involve branches on modern processor architectures, because it can be implemented using conditional moves (e.g. on x86), predication (e.g. ARM), or select instructions (e.g. some GPUs).

Comment: njuffa, if you use an unsigned integer type of suitable size, say `((uint32_t)0U - (uint32_t)(!!y))`, the architecture does not matter: **unsigned** integer arithmetic is modular (`0U - 1U == UINT_MAX`, regardless of architecture), and all you need to ensure is that the type has a one-less-than-a-power-of-two largest representable value. So, any of the fixed-size unsigned integer types will work just fine for such expressions, portably. (Useful for SSE/AVX vectorization, too.)

Comment: Just a note the ternary operator likely wont be optimized to cmove if the optimizer thinks either of the results cost too much to pre-calculate.  If you want to force cmove, in all cases you need to first perform the calculations to determine the values.  So:  return (f) ? A() : B() might not produce a cmove, but a = A(), b = B(); return (f) ? a : b; will

Answer (score 5):

```
static_cast<bool>(y) * x
```

Comment: I should donwvote this as 'too simple' .  Where are your FP series expansions?   :)

Answer (score 0):

Just take y and use its bits to form a string of all 1's if it was nonzero, then AND this with x. The silly way of doing this is linearly but you can do it with a binary method too (not given).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int foo(int x, int y) {
    int z = 0;
    for(int z = 1; z < CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int); z ++) {
        y |= y << z;
    }
    return x & y;
}

int main() {
    printf("%lx\n", foo(0x1000, 0xdead));
    return 0;
}
```

That should run in constant time. You can unroll the loop of course.